# How to authorize pocket API call from Python script when posting links to my own pocket account?

Tags: python, pocket

I am writing a python script to add links to my own Pocket account. I am following these steps.

1. **Get Consumer Key:** I have a consumer key generated from Pocket developer app
2. **Generate request token:** I have generated a request token with below code

   ```
   pocket_get_request_token_url = "https://getpocket.com/v3/oauth/request"
   headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
             "X-Accept": "application/json"}

   params = {"consumer_key": consumer_key,
             "redirect_uri": "pocketapp1234:authorizationFinished"}

   pocketOAuth = requests.post(pocket_get_request_token_url,
                               json=params, headers=headers)

   request_token = json.loads(pocketOAuth.text)["code"]
   ```
3. **Authorize request token:** Step 3 is to authorize the token using below code. I don't know how to run this block for a python script.

   ```
   pocket_auth_request_token_url = "https://getpocket.com/auth/authorize"
   params = {"request_token": request_token,
         "redirect_uri": "pocketapp1234:authorizationFinished"}
   authResp = requests.post(pocket_auth_request_token_url, json=params)
   ```
4. **Generate Access token:** Step 4 is to then generate access token. If I go ahead and generate an access token, using the below code,

   ```
   pocket_get_access_token_url = "https://getpocket.com/v3/oauth/authorize"
   headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
          "X-Accept": "application/json"}

   params = {"consumer_key": consumer_key,
         "code": request_token}

   accessResp = requests.post(pocket_get_access_token_url,
                          json=params, headers=headers)

   access_token = json.loads(accessResp.text)["access_token"]
   ```

When I run the above block of code, I get the below error.

> x-error-code : 158  x-error : User rejected code

So my question is, If I am trying to add links to my pocket account using python script, I am obviously not running a web application, **so how can I authorize the generated request token so that I can proceed to generate an access token**?

Answer (score 4):

To add on to Yue's answer, the redirect URI is inconsequential if you're running this from a script. I ran into this issue as well and used `input` to make my script interactive: https://gist.github.com/alexpyoung/7e241a8f3f805630f0f66a1cf0763675#file-pocket_import-L71

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to authorize a Pocket Developer API and followed your steps. However, I tried a different method in Step 3 according to [Getting Started With the Pocket Developer API](http://www.jamesfmackenzie.com/getting-started-with-the-pocket-developer-api/#step-3-visit-the-pocket-website-to-authorize-your-app).

You should modify the following URL with your request token and redirect URI, then open it in browser: https://getpocket.com/auth/authorize?request_token=YOUR_REQUEST_TOKEN&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI